# Vim registers standards

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I was thinking of setting my registers to equal common coding techniques. For
example, I was thinking of doing this:

```
:let @i = "int i=0;"
```

Then I would set `f` for for loop, `w` for while loop etc. Is this a bad technique or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you could use snippets instead. Try to look at snipmate plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

You can just type "inti TAB" and it'll expand to "int i=0;" if you wish.

It already has a lot of snippets to many languages but you can configure it to do what you want.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that existed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

For simple expansions, the built-in abbreviations will suffice:

```
:iab ii int i=0;
```

If you want parameter expansion, different "stops" to fill in data, and other advanced features, various *snippets* plugins (on http://www.vim.org/) offer this functionality; one of the first and broadly used ones is *snipMate*.